# Compile assembler in nasm on mac os

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly, nasm

So, i write some instruction on asm, and compile them.

```
nasm -f macho test.asm
```

Now, nasm generate obj file, test.o

```
gcc test.o
```

Returned next error:

> - ld: warning: ignoring file test.o, file was built for unsupported file
>     format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
> - Undefined
>     symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_main", referenced from:
> - start in crt1.10.6.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

in gcc line, i used -arch i386 (x86_64), returned same error.

Can anybody help? :)

Comment: Did you try `-f macho64` instead `macho`?

Answer (score 6):

These commands work for me (OS X 10.12 x64):

```
nasm -f macho test.asm -DDARWIN
ld -o test test.o -arch i386 -lc -no_pie -macosx_version_min 10.12 -lSystem
```

Answer (score 1):

`macho` is a 32 bit format.
Try to use `macho64` instead of `macho`. Complete line:

```
nasm -f macho64 test.asm
```

Comment: Coodey, NASM returned: 
fatal: unrecognised output format `macho64' - use -hf for a list
type `nasm -h' for help.   And nasm -hf return this http://joxi.ru/b6soUdg5CbCIUDRXAyo

Comment: @Aleeewka Yeah, I had the same error when I started using `nasm` on the Mac. You have to get the latest version of it.

Comment: Coodey, I downloading last version. You can use macho64 in last?

Comment: @Aleeewka The version I have is `2.10.05` (updated a while ago) and `macho64` works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your nasm version and use the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/nasm -f macho64 ${file}
ld  -o ${file_path}/${file_base_name} -e _main ${file_path}/${file_base_name}.o
${file_path}/${file_base_name}
```